# Difference between ps –ef|grep java and ps –ef|grep *.java

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to find all running java process in a unix box. I am confused between

```
ps –ef|grep java
```

and

```
ps –ef|grep *.java
```

Which one is correct and what is the exact difference?

PS: Both returns different set of results

Output of `ps –ef|grep *.java`

```
ps -ef | grep *.java
aaassa1  7507  2304  0 11:49 pts/4    00:00:00 grep *.java
```

Answer (score 6):

`grep` does just text match, it doesn't have idea of process name or filename etc.

that is, if you have a python script called `likejava.py`, it will be in result too.

Back to your question, your `*.java` is not good, because grep works with regex, not glob patterns.

You could try:

`ps -ef|grep $(which java)` this will list java processes, but only for your default java installation. If you have more than one Java installed, e.g. your Jboss with java7, tomcat with java6, and eclipse with java5, this will fail.

There is another tool called `pgrep`. You could give it a try, e.g.

```
pgrep -l java
```

you could do `man pgrep` to get more info:

```
pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes
```

**EDIT** add a small **ps..|grep trick**

just saw your output in the question:

You have `grep *.java` in output, it is a good example. `grep *.java` is not java process but it has text "java". so it is there.

You could avoid it by `ps...|grep [j]ava` works for bash.

Answer (score 2):

The first is correct.  In the second, your shell expands the `*.java` based on your current working directory, with fun results.

Exactly what those results are... I'm guessing here, but assuming you have files `foo.java` and `bar.java` in your current dir, the latter is effectively doing:

```
ps -ef | grep bar.java foo.java
```

<del>Which, *I believe*, will simply search for bar.java inside foo.java, ignoring the piped input from `ps`.  But don't quote me on that -</del> the point is that it is almost surely not what you want.

Comment: I have updated the question with output of ps –ef|grep *.java. Something can be inferred from this?

Comment: I think it would imply that the latter part of my answer, re: ignoring the ps input, is wrong.  I'll remove that.